# Troubles with baking a fluid

Tags: modeling, animation, physics, fluid-simulation

Recently, I tried doing [CG Geek's wine glass tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkivGauxY). Everything went well up until the fluid simulation part. Sometimes, the fluid doesn't bake. Other times, the fluid has some weird shape that does not collide with the the wine glass ([first try .blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/42865)). Currently, I have no idea what the problem is. I tried doing it again and I got the same problem ([second try .blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/42867)).

I'm open to any suggestions, thanks in advance.

Recalculating the normals didn't seem to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the glass mesh, the normals (direction it's facing) of the faces are not all pointing out to the air as they should.
So the fluid simulator does not know how to calculate the shape of the glass obstacle correctly.

**To fix *(EDIT) your second try*:**

With the glass selected,

1. Go into edit mode. (tab)
2. select everything. (a key)
3. Then "recalculate normals".  (ctrl+n  This is also in the tool panel at the left, in the "Shading / UVs" tab.)

More tips:

- You could make the domain object much smaller for more efficient
  simulation.  So you can resize it to just where the fluid will be.
- Now you can turn up the Domain's fluid resolution...
- You might want to make the glass a little thicker towards the bottom,
  so the fluid does not stick through.

*(EDIT.  Noticed my instructions were just for your second try.)*

**To fix your first try:**

On both the glass and fluid shape:

(In object mode, look at the scale of the objects, they're negative numbers, they need to be positive for the fluid sim to figure out the shapes.)

- Apply the scale.  (Ctl+A then click scale)  Applying the scale makes the scale 1,1,1.)
- Then recalculate normals.  (If you recalculate the normals when the object is inverted, it looks ok, but it confuses the fluid sim.
- (Also I didn't test if you needed to, but I'd also remove doubles on your meshes, the fluid shape has quite a few.)

Comment: Recalculating the normals didn't seem to fix it. Thanks for helping.

Comment: I edited the answer to also work for your first try.